# Resize content for "frame" on .aspx page which draws product content from suppliers' page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, frameset

I have a retail store site, no online sales, which displays the webpage of our supplier in a "frame" in order to have the most accurate and up to date information for our customers. ([example](http://www.wbs.ae/WindowDetail.aspx?R=http://www.scott-sports.com/gb_en/team/127/xc_race&B=MOUNTAIN_BIKE&U=Mountain.aspx))

My issue is that the size of the page it is pulling in doesn't fit in the frame. It looks pretty poor, and part of the content is obscured. Is there a way to scale the content drawn in to the size of the frame?

The same site also has an intermittent issue with the Flash banner loading. When it doesn't load, the layout of the header on the page is awful. Any ideas there will also be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically resize my iframe, avoiding the browser security crossdomain restrictions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495700/how-can-i-dynamically-resize-my-iframe-avoiding-the-browser-security-crossdomai)

Answer (score 1):

How to dynamically resize an iframe, when iframe content is on a 3rd-party domain:

[How can I dynamically resize my iframe, avoiding the browser security crossdomain restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495700/how-can-i-dynamically-resize-my-iframe-avoiding-the-browser-security-crossdomain)